# Encrypt files in transfer to server, and on server, with multiple keys

Tags: encryption

I am currently in the process of making an online desktop of sorts, and one of the offerings that I will advertise is that the data on your online desktop is encrypted with your password, not our key. So instead of checking the password with a database then decrypting the data with our key, I would like to have each customers data encrypted with their password. The server will then try to decrypt the data with the password. If the decrypting is successful, the data is sent to the client for JavaScript or another language to organize and display. Otherwise, a failed password attempt is sent back. I would also like to completely take myself out of the equation with the passwords by making it impossible for the server to log the password or see the password in any way whatsoever, so your security is in your hands, not ours.

My question is what language would be best suited for that, and the proper methods and functions for doing this. Once I have that information, I will learn that language, and those methods and functions to do this.

I am not too worried about a quick release of hiring a dev as rite now this is a project I challenged myself to, and doing it for fun.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use *any* language. Besides, there is something wrong with your requirements. If you want to take the server out of the equation, then there cannot be any decryption on the server. All decryption must be happening on the client. You can certainly store ciphertexts on the server.

Comment: @ArtjomB Agreed, which instantly rules out JavaScript as a client side language.

Comment: @LukePark JavaScript (in the browser) is still possible. It can be packaged as a browser extension. It can even be delivered from the server. In the latter case the server developers might add a backdoor to the delivered JavaScript, but that is a problem with all software, because we nowadays generally have automatic update mechanisms. For example, WhatsApp claims end-to-end security now, but what hinders them to push out a new version of the app, that sends the symmetric keys back to the WhatsApp servers, other than a potential reputation loss?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Possible but not recommended.  Its generally consider a poor idea to implement any part of your crypto in browser Javascript, purely due to the fact that the script itself must be delivered to the client before it can be executed.  Browser extensions sure, but no self respecting dev would do this, its just hindrance to the end user.